# Equivalent fread using ifstream

Tags: c++

I want to use `ifstream` to read `n` blocks of data like `fread`, is there a way to do implement similar functionality in C++ using `ifstream`?

I tried to load the TGA file, and its header looks like:

```
struct TgaHeader {
    char identSize;
    char colorMapType;
    char imageType;
    unsigned short colorMapStart;
    unsigned short colorMapLength;
    unsigned char colorMapBits;
    unsigned short xstart;
    unsigned short ystart;
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
    char bits;
    char descriptor;
};
```

Using `fread` to read a header:

```
TgaHeader tgaHeader;
fread( &tgaHeader, 18/* sizeof( TgaHeader )*/, 1, pFile );
```

Now I want to use it with `ifstream`, but there are no equivalent functions available. `ifstream` only offers `read` function which allows reading a pointer of `n` size. So how could I say reading `n` headers of `x` bytes using `fstream`?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you familiar with [the basics](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)? What have you tried so far? How did that fail?

Comment: What do you need that the [`read`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/basic_istream/read) member function doesn't do?

Comment: try `your_fstream.read((char*)&tgaHeader, sizeof(TgaHeader))`... :-/

Comment: @Tony: Thanks. I know the syntax, what I asked was is there an equivalent function like `fread` for `ifstream`. Because let's say if I have to read in 10 TgaHeader, then I have to explicitly do the multiplication part.

Comment: @Chan : So you have to type a `*` instead of a `,`? That's the dealbreaker?

Comment: @ildjarn: I guess you didn't get what I meant.

Comment: @Chen : I agree, I don't understand -- you're saying with `fread` you would pass `size, count`, and I'm saying with `basic_istream<>::read` you would pass `size * count`. I just don't see the problem.

Comment: @Chan: yes, you do the multiplication. The fread struct size / #records thing is probably an historic oddity from the days when some operating systems had filesystems with database-table-like file access modes that encouraged such a perspective. In a modern filesystem binary I/O modes are byte based, with no inherent conception of contents as homogeneous records.

Comment: Sorry all, after trying for a while, I think I should have asked a better question. In fact, I was trying to accomplish thing that doesn't exists, there are no such interface like that in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments under the question say, you want [`basic_istream<>::read()`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/basic-istream.html#idx178) and to use `size * count` instead of the two separate arguments of `fread()`.